Does Aeron support io_uring?
I'm using the Aeron open source for some POCs, and using C version of media driver, does it support the io_uring?
Also we are using java version of Aeron cluster and archive, what about them?

If you are using C code, why the Java tag?

Because I've mention Cluster & Archive too

Aeron currently does not support io_uring after some early testing did not show performance benefits. Aeron has premium extensions for kernel bypass that include ef_vi (Solarflare), DPDK (Cloud), and VMA Express (Mellanox) that do show significant latency and throughput improvements.
